# Algorithm for increasing and decreasing a float in a passive rating system

Tags: ruby, algorithm, mongoid, ranking, recommendation-engine

I'd like to implement a passive rating system, and though this seems like a standard problem, I've been unable to find any implemented solutions.

My use case is:

As a user, I didn't like a book and want a different book. (this decreases the book's rating)
As a user, I finished reading the book and marked it finished. (this increases the book's rating)

In ruby pseudocode:

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :subject, type: String
  field :rating, type: Float
end

def request_replacement
  self.rating -= 0.01
  return Book.where(subject: self.subject).all.sample
end

@book.request_replacement
```

The rating influences the likelihood the book will be recommended to readers in the future.

I initialized each book's rating as 0.50. I naively figured each time a user requested a substitute, I'd decrease the book's rating (-0.01), and each time a user marked the book finished, I'd increase the book's rating (+0.01).

I am afraid, however, that a bunch of early negative reviews could push a book's rating so low it's never recommended, and that too many positive reviews would lead to excessive recommendation of the book.

Is there a conventional way to increase and decrease the value of the float to prevent such runaway effects (perhaps asymptotically approaching 1 and 0 respectively?)

Thanks for your time and insights!

Comment: The simplest approach is to decrease step of "+rating" after every positive change and increase it back after negative change, and vice versa. This will slow down rating growth in case of many "one sign" consecutive rating changes.

Comment: If you want to prevent early over- and underrating, use some kind of dynamic coefficient, for example, `1 - k*exp(-mt)`, where t is time from start or count of rating changes, k, m - coefficients to be chosen (e.g. k=0.5 will make rating change start on 50% and grow to 100% asymptotically)

Comment: OK, so t is time (or rating count), k is the rate of change, what is m exactly?

Comment: 1-k shows the point at which rating starts (if k=0.5, the whole coefficient = 0.5 at t=0 and then grows up to 1), m is the "speed" of growth (the more is m, the faster coefficient reaches ~1).

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. I understand. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a kind of coefficient, that starts from some value and asymptotically approaches 1, you can use exponential function e<sup>-x</sup> in the following way:

```
1 - k*exp(-mt)
```

where `t` is time or count of book queries, `m` is "speed" of growth (the bigger is m, the faster whole coefficient reaches ~1), `1 - k` is the value at t = 0.

[image: http://fooplot.com]

Here, k = 0.5 and m = 1/20